# how to call a file from Main method

Tags: c#, class, program-entry-point

I`ve just started studying C# and trying to do some practice.

[image: Main method]

[image: File]

I want to call this File
like i did in Main method with other files
but because it contains few methods

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class StringCopies
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(test("C Sharp"));
            Console.WriteLine(test("JS"));
            Console.WriteLine(test("a"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static string test(string str)
        {
            return str.Length < 2 ? str : str.Substring(0, 2) + str.Substring(0, 2) + str.Substring(0, 2) + str.Substring(0, 2);
        }
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // new _strings_ZZaremaZ().Run();
            //new IfIntPositiveAndNegativeTrue().Run();
            //new computeIntIfEqualTriple().Run();
            //new ifParameterOrSumEquals20().Run();
            //new toLower().Run();
            //new longestWord().Run();
            //new SplitReverse().Run();
            //new FileSize().Run();
            //new MultiplyArrays().Run();
            //?????new StringLastItem().Run();
            //new StringContains().Run();
            //new MathMaxMinxyz().Run();
            //new toLower3firstToUpperifLess4().Run();
            //new ArraySum().Run();
            //new oneOfThemIs30orSum30().Run();
            //StringCopies myProgram = new StringCopies();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't include your code as image, but as text (formatted as code sample)

Comment: `ConsoleApplication1.StringCopies.Main(null)` ?

Comment: i want to call "class StringCopies" from "class Program". If its possible

Comment: i did it before with other classes, but they were void, so it was easy

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Please take time out for a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com//tour) and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com//help). You might also want to read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com//questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I`ll do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> i want to call "class StringCopies" from "class Program". If its
>   possible – Ярослав Кудрявцев

Yes, possible. Put this code into Main of Program

`StringCopies.Main(null);`

like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // new _strings_ZZaremaZ().Run();
        //new IfIntPositiveAndNegativeTrue().Run();
        //new computeIntIfEqualTriple().Run();
        //new ifParameterOrSumEquals20().Run();
        //new toLower().Run();
        //new longestWord().Run();
        //new SplitReverse().Run();
        //new FileSize().Run();
        //new MultiplyArrays().Run();
        //?????new StringLastItem().Run();
        //new StringContains().Run();
        //new MathMaxMinxyz().Run();
        //new toLower3firstToUpperifLess4().Run();
        //new ArraySum().Run();
        //new oneOfThemIs30orSum30().Run();

        StringCopies.Main(null);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: i meant
to put that class which is including a function "static Void Main" and "public static test" into a Program.cs

Comment: It gets messy. I want to have different files for different classes. For example I was using this "new MathMaxMinxyz().Run();" to call a class with one void method.

Comment: So what is the problem with my answer `StringCopies.Main(null);`?

Comment: When I'm putting "StringsCopies.Main(null)"in Program.cs Main I have an error

Comment: Ok, what error? Or do I have to guess? If you really need help then please see [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Error CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Class1.Main(object)' and 'Class1.Main(object)' ConsoleApplication1

Comment: did you try to use `ConsoleApplication1.StringCopies.Main(null)` instead of `StringCopies.Main(null);`?

Comment: If I do it this way, i need to make that all methods open in StringsCopies. IDK why but when I'm trying to compile it shows a pop window "There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?"

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Had to rename that main function and make it public